# All of a sudden i started seeing an insertion of a period after two spaces, even in programming mode files

Tags: whitespace, programming

I started noticing this after an update, every two spaces at end of a word/symbol places a period at the end.
I am not sure how to debug this or where to look.

any pointers appreciated.

Comment: "after an update" -- what did you update?  If you roll back, does the problem go away?

Comment: I restarted emacs and it is not there anymore. Seems like I switched so some mode that does that. not because of the update. I am still not sure which mode this is part of.